# Create a record in table A and assign its id to table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of companies and for each of them, I need to generate a UUID in another table.

```
companies table
detail_id (currently NULL for all companies)
```

```
details table
id
uuid
date
...
```

I'd like to update all companies with newly created detail like this:

```
UPDATE companies
SET details_id =
(
 INSERT INTO details
 (uuid, date)
 VALUES (uuid_generate_v1(), now()::date)
 RETURNING id
)
```

But that gives me a syntax error since I can't use `INSERT INTO` inside `UPDATE`.
What is a proper way to create a row in the details table and immediately set the newly created id in the companies table?

(I am using Postgres)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_rows as (
  INSERT INTO details ("uuid", "date")
  VALUES (uuid_generate_v1(), current_date)
  RETURNING id
)
update companies
   set details_id = new_rows.id
from new_rows
```

Comment: It inserts only one detail. E.g. it does not create a separate detail for each company. Is there a way to create as many details as companies?